# How to convert .m2ts .vob Video to mkv without losing quality in COLAB FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, google-colaboratory

I want to convert .m2ts and vob videos to .mkv in same resolution and quality, so how to do it in COLAB?
I used a script All in One 1.9.1 it converts successfully but output file is verly low quality and its avc codec is version 3 while i want it to be version High@L4.1.

I have mounted my gdrive and will use it as source of videos.

All in one 1.9.1
https://colab.research.google.com/github/pcodejs/Codemaster/blob/master/All_in_One_1_9_1.ipynb

Comment: Don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Since MKV can handle most formats you can [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (like a copy and paste) the contents of the inputs thus fulfilling your requirement of, *"`.m2ts` and `.vob` videos to `.mkv` **without losing quality**."*

```
ffmpeg -i input.vob -map 0 -map -0:d -c copy output.mkv
```

If you get error `Can't write packet with unknown timestamp` add the `-fflags +genpts` input option (put it before `-i`).